# RavenDB sharding causes updates to act as inserts

Tags: c#, ravendb, sharding

I'm trying to setup a simple proof of concept for my workplace using RavenDB.  The demo has 2 shards doing the basic round-robin strategy currently.  It then has 2 more shards to replicate each of those 2, as failover.

We went through and saved various Business records.  We would get Ids, such as matt-businesses-35, and bob-businesses-42 which looked right.  However, when we edit one, it doesn't update the existing record, it does an insert.  And most often, we end up with an Id similar to matt-bob-business-42 in addition to the original.

We followed this page as a guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh547101.aspx

We have however modified it for sharding, by replacing the code in DataDocumentstore.cs:

```
var shards = new Dictionary<string, IDocumentStore>
                 {
                     {"bob", new DocumentStore() {Url = "http://bob:8080"}},
                     {"matt", new DocumentStore() {Url = "http://matt:8080"}},
                 };

var shardStrategy = new ShardStrategy(shards);

instance = new ShardedDocumentStore(shardStrategy);
instance.Conventions.IdentityPartsSeparator = "-";
instance.Initialize();
```

The Edit actions look as follows:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
{
    var model = DocumentSession.Load<Business>(id);
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(string id, Business business)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            DocumentSession.Store(business);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(business);
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Did we set something up wrong to get these weird issues?  It seems like a fairly simple setup, but updates always insert with a new key name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *Edit* action is wrong. Instead of calling `.Store()` once again with your edited data, you need to load the entity first and then map the changes to the loaded instance. RavenDBs session automatically tracks the changes on that instance and updates the document in the database when you call `.SaveChanges()`.

In your specific case, I don't know where you call .SaveChanges, but I guess it's inside the OnActionExecuted on your base controller or the EndRequest in your global.asax. Either way works. All you have to do is to load the business by id, change its properties and you're done. No need for storing the document again.

AutoMapper may help you update the instance with its overload of the Map() method, which takes preinstantiated objects.

Comment: I haven't got Automapper do successfully map the object for me, but mapping the properties manually is working for sure.